# Where is verification to check sender email address set?

Tags: php, validation, email, sender

I have 2 different domains hosted by the same provider. On one of the domains, i can send an email using the PHP mail function with a from address that does not exist e.g. noreply@myrealdomainname.com.

On my other domain (which i know is hosted on a different server), the mail does not reach the recipient and an error email appears in the catchall mailbox of the domain saying that the sender address could not be verified. I can obviously fix the problem by using a valid from email address  but i would like to understand where the setting is which forces the one domain to have the check done and the other one not.

Is it a setting somewhere on the server or a piece of software running on the server? I have asked my hosting company but have not had any success with an answer.

Many thanks
Bianca

Comment: far too broad a question: there's DNS, there's SMTP configuration, there's MTA configuration, there's account configuration.

Comment: Is the a replyto address in the error email? Check the email headers (What server mailed it etc) That may provide hints to what is generating the errors.